# Thread Synchronization in C++/CLI using only Atomic operations

Tags: .net, multithreading, synchronization, c++-cli, atomic

I am currently trying to achieve thread synchronization in C++ .net using only atomic operations using the System::Threading::Interlocked class in .net.  I'm not very experienced at all with multithreading and I'm trying to use lock-less thread synchronization.  Currently I have created a class called settings that contains static variables that I need to share between threads.  I then created two static functions in it, one for setting the static data members, and one for reading them.  Currently this is what one of my static synchronization functions looks like.  **I do understand that if more than two threads enter this function at once, they could become stuck in the while loop forever, but only two threads will be needing this function**, a GUI thread and the main thread that will read settings and dispatch work to worker threads.

```
//object is handle to instance of settings class that also contains non-static
//members that will contain each threads copy of the data.
void Settings::SetStaticVariables(Settings ^object)
{
    int returnvalue;

    //canchange variable is a static integer of the class "Settings"
    returnvalue = Threading::Interlocked::Increment(Settings::canchange);
    if(returnvalue > 1)
    {
        while(Settings::canchange > 1)
        {
            //perhaps eventually I will find an alternative to telling the thread
            //to sleep for a defined amount of time, maybe when I learn how to use events
            //for now this will do, speed is not very important for this data sync as 
            //it does not occure often
            Threading::Thread::Sleep(50);
        }
    }
    //data synchronization of static members here

    //decrement allowing waiting threads to exit while loop
    Threading::Interlocked::Decrement(Settings::canchange);
};
```

My question is, do you see anything flawed that will not give me what I am expecting or is this whole idea for synchronization flawed?

Comment: "I'm not very experienced at all with multithreading and I'm trying to use lock-less thread synchronization."  This is likely to end poorly.  Writing correct multithreaded code is hard, and doing so lock-free is harder still.  Have you tried using a lock and profiled it to see whether the locking is an actual performance hot-spot?

Comment: I have not tried using any locks, but being that performance for this section of code is not at all important, then I very well could try using locks.  If you believe that's the best route to take, then I definitely could use them.  I just figured it would be good to get experience with lock-less synchronization because I read on an article about multithreading that it's best to use locks as little as possible.  Also, I eventually will be (trying to) code where speed does matter, but for now, I suppose I could get familiar with locks.

Comment: @James: +1. +10 if I could. @Jake: It's true that avoiding locks is a good practice in general, but far more important is the rule about avoiding *lock-free synchronization* - specifically, "Never write lock-free synchronization code unless you are an expert with several decades of experience and you have a good team of multithreaded programmers and advanced mathematicians ready to check your work."

Comment: Right:  start by getting familiar with the fundamentals of thread synchronization using locks.  Once you are familiar with the fundamentals, atomics can be used for very basic lock-free programming, though until you are very comfortable with writing synchronization code, I'd avoid trying to do anything too complex with them (I don't at all mean this in a condescending way; I have written more than my fair share of threading bugs and I firmly believe in sticking to simple, straightforward, frequently used patterns that are easy to reason about.)

Comment: Well I'm convinced, I will use locks for now.  After doing some more research I found that the compiler and processor sometimes reorder operations that could cause data in the synchronized section to be altered after leaving it.  Maybe eventually I will experiment with another program solely for the purpose of testing data synchronization without locks but for now, I will use them.  Hopefully when I get to college and take Computer Sciences I will have a better understanding of parallelism.  Thanks for the advice guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a good eye for multithreading if you were able to determine that this is safe for up to two threads only.  Don't let people discourage you from studying lock-free techniques.

You could use `InterlockedExchange` instead of increment, which would remove the possible deadlock with >=2 threads.  However, this algorithm is not lock-free programming at all, rather you are implementing your own lock.  Of course this means you will run into many issues of performance and correctness that have already been solved by the library locking classes (`Monitor` and friends).

Here's what it would look like with [`Interlocked::Exchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3fxt78a.aspx)

```
// try to acquire lock
while (0 != Interlocked::Exchange(Settings::canchange, 1))
{
   Thread::Sleep(50);
}

MemoryBarrierAcquire();

// update shared variables

// flush cached writes
MemoryBarrierRelease();
// unlock
Settings::canchange = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I will not try without locks until after I understand using them and multithreading in general better than I do now.  Also, if you could, how exactly is "lock-free" multithreading different than what I did implementing my own lock (I guess I probably should have understood it better before even asking the question LOL).

Comment: @JAKE: For an example of truly lock-free programming, consider the Win32 [`SList API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684121.aspx), which is useful for a multi-producer single-consumer threadsafe queue.  I've actually implemented an identical data structure in C++ using the Interlocked API, the only difference being that mine is type-safe thanks to the magic of C++ templates.  Immutability often plays a critical role in lock-free programming.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but when I make changes with one thread, does memorybarrier flush the processor cache as well or do I need to use volatile writes and reads to maintain cache coherency?  Or is that automatically maintained by the processor?

Comment: A memory barrier prevents the processor from reordering reads and writes across it.  When the system bus implements a cache coherency protocol, then actually flushing the cache may not be necessary -- most of the effect is actually on the CPU pipeline engine including out-of-order execution and speculative execution.  Volatile is something else entirely, it prevents the compiler from rearranging or merging or generating instructions to speculatively perform memory access.  (Except in VC++ 2008 and later, volatile also adds a memory barrier.)

Comment: So do I really have any use for volatile at all?  I've found that it's rather useless for multithreading in most cases from a few articles and answered questions here and there.  Should I use it in case I come across a variable that is shared and changed frequently by a single thread to make sure it doesn't stay in a register or should I completely ignore the word? (or should I just ask a new question instead of tacking on more comments ;)

Comment: @Jake: You probably don't have any use for volatile.  It's more for kernel-mode code interacting with devices, where reading the same address twice might not only give different results, but change the state of the device.  Also very useful in embedded systems, on variables shared with an ISR.  And in unix-style signal handlers, which run on the same thread, so hardware out-of-order execution isn't a factor.  If you aren't doing any of those things, you probably won't use it.

Comment: @Jake: However, there is one additional effect.  Like `const`, the C++ type system allows adding `volatile` implicitly but not removing it.  So declaring a variable as `volatile` can let the compiler help you check that it is only passed to thread-safe APIs.